# Simulate the effect of a static C variable in Java method

Tags: java

In Java can a method have anything close to a static variable in C?Although Java doesn't provide one
That is,it would be initialized only once and keep latest value in subsequent recursive invocations

I could pass it back to the method to have the latest value and achieve 'initalize only once' based on some condition which holds true only once

```
  int fun(.....,Nthcall,PseudoStatic)
   {if(NthCall==1)
     PseudoStatic=10
    //rest of code
      Pseudostatic=100
       fun(.....,Nthcall+1,PseudoStatic)
    }
```

Isn't there something better?

Comment: You could potentially implement a helper function.

Comment: (That said, static mutable state is widely considered a code smell in Java.)

Comment: A `static` variable is just a global variable. The Java equivalent is `static` fields on a class.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Heck, static mutable state is a code smell anywhere.

Comment: @millimoose - to be clear, that's per classloader

Comment: @Brian Agnew Yes that would be logical but it would expose it to all methods of the class.

Comment: @BrianAgnew True, but if you're at the point where you know you need state shared across classloaders (eurgh) you're not asking questions at this level on SO. Wittgenstein's ladder and all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do something like this

```
public void test()
{
    StaticVar<Integer> s1 = new StaticVar<Integer>(){};

    StaticVar<Long> s2 = new StaticVar<Long>(){};

    Integer v1 = s1.get();
    System.out.println(v1);
    s1.set( v1==null? 1 : v1+1 );

    Long v2 = s2.get();
    System.out.println(v2);
    s2.set( v2==null? 1 : v2*2 );
}

public abstract class StaticVar<V>
{
    public V get()
    {
        return (V)class2value.get(this.getClass());
    }

    public void set(V value)
    {
        class2value.put(this.getClass(), value);
    }

    static WeakHashMap<Class,Object> class2value = new WeakHashMap<>();
}
```

It's not thread safe though. We can simply add `synchronized(class2value)`. Or use a weak concurrent hash map.

Comment: So every class in which a method will need a static variable will have to extend StaticVar.Can you please explain the line 
   static WeakHashMap<Class,Object> class2value = new WeakHashMap<>(); Is that syntactically well formed? Isn't the type parameter missing on right hand side .Also the runtime type of the object is used as a key to the map.How would that work if two static variables of same type are required?

Comment: 1. no, StaticVar is a standalone utility class. 2. I'm using Java 7, `new Foo<>()` is valid syntax. 3. it's ok if s1 and s2 are the same type, e.g. both are `Static<Integer>`, try it.

Comment: Yes it runs on Java 7.Only gives a warning that the type parameter is missing.I am still trying to comprehend why there is no key collision.Say I have s1 and s2 of type StaticVar<Integer> so getClass() returns same type for s1,s2.How are the get() and put() methods working correctly?

Comment: Figured it out now..I was comparing getclass() of v1 and v2 where as i needed to compare that of s1 and s2..which are different..Even though using static class member is cleaner and simpler..ur answer demonstrates a closer simulation.Thanks

Comment: yeah, don't use my solution, it's just for fun.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just declare a variable static to the class ? See the [tutorial on instance and class variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more info.

Note that this isn't thread-safe if multiple threads use the same class. and consequently you may be better off defining a class member variable per invocation.